# Javac is not recognized even after setting the path

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have installed my jdk file. I have also set my path in the advanced setting in the user variable as well as system variable. When I tried to compile my program through  javac filename.java the command prompt is showing javac is not recognized as an internal or external command. I again set my path but still the problem remains the same

Comment: Did you set `JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: In addition to setting `JAVA_HOME`, you may have to reopen the terminal.

Comment: also can you check the output of the command : echo %JAVA_HOME% in a new command prompt?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is irrelevant. javac doesn't use that environment variable. Your PATH must contain the JDK/bin directory, and you need to really restart the command prompt after setting it.

Comment: I think @JBNizet is right, unless you set JAVA_HOME in the PATH, it is irrelevant.

Comment: It sounds like you've not set your path *correctly*. What value did you set in your path, precisely? And have you checked that javac.exe is actually there? Does running just "java" work? Which version of java is this?

Comment: It's Java 8th edition with jdk1.8.0_0.5 version. I have also tried reopening the command prompt but still the problem remains same. Even my path is correct

Comment: I have tried JAVA_HOME. But their is no difference. I have reopened my command prompt and tried to compile my program but still it's showing javac is not recogy

Comment: Again, JAVA_HOME is irrelevant, for the reason said above. Answer the questions in the comments above and you will have solved your problem; anything else is wasting your time doing trial-and-error for no reason.

Comment: Can you show us how your PATH looks? Maybe you did something wrong, did you try to remove everything then reinstall java and add to PATH again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem happens when you define your JAVA_HOME under User variables and not under the system variables.

Try moving the JAVA_HOME to System Variables and restart the command prompt. It will work like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see that the System variable `Path` has an entry to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. But that location doesn't have the Javac executable.(`javac.exe`). Adding the JDK bin path solved the problem for me. (Added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` to `Path`)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this on Windows follow these:

Step 1:Go to advanced system settings in property page of Control panel

Step 2:Select Advanced Tab

Step 3:Select Environmental Variables Tab on Bottom

Step 4:See under System Variables Heading

Step 5:Locate "Path" variable and click edit

Step 6:You will see a new editing window

Step 7:click Browse Button on Right and locate bin of JDK installed on your System

And at last select ok, ok and ok! Thus you are all set

If your java application crashes
Then follow:

Step 1:Search for Configure Java application on Windows search tab

Step 2:Select Java tab

Step 3:You will see user and system tab

Step 4:One by One on each tab select Find button on bottom

Step 5:Locate Java Runtime or jrex.x.x_x named folder and thus all is done!

Answer (score 1):

As [JDK INSTALLATION ON MICROSOFT WINDOWS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-A7E27B90-A28D-4237-9383-A58B416071CA) suggests that adding the full path of JDK-14\bin to PATH VARIABLE for permanently, didn't work for me and adding a new variable to system variable JAVA_HOME with same path as PATH variable "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin" solves my issue. Give the above path to both JAVA_HOME and PATH system variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many methods there are to resolve this problem, but I have the easiest way to do this. Just follow the following methods:

1. After installing jdk, open **Advanced system setting** which is located in **System**.
2. Then open environment variables.
3. Under **system variables** search for **Path** and delete it.
4. Again under **system variables** click on **New** command. Under variable name write `Path` and under variable value copy the path of jdk you installed *<< C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin >>.* and save it.
5. Now open cmd prompt and write `javac`. It will work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. after setting path as described above.

1. I opened the command prompt
2. typed Path%JAVA_HOME%
3. press enter

It worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Mannually copy the JDK, bin directory. (EX: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin)
2. Then run following command in cmd. 
   **"C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java" -version**
   [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LmPA.png)

Seems you JDK is corrupted. Download new JDK and setup Environment as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, as on the oracle website it is mentioned to append the directory to path system variable, but it worked for me when I appended the path **user** variable. Please make the changes in path user variable. This is for jdk 14, it comes with a private jre and recognised when path is added.